# Docky artifacting on edges

Tags: docky, intel-hd, visual-artifacts

I've got 2 laptops running Quantal 32-bit, one with a 2nd gen Core i5 and another with a 3rd gen Core i3. On my i5 laptop, Docky in 3d mode produces a translucent green artifact on both the left and right side while moving my cursor over the icons (with or without zoom enabled).

From what I've read on this forum and others, it seems to be a driver issue. However, both my laptops are using the i915 driver and the issue does not occur on my i3 laptop at all.

Comment: Screenshot? It might help to see the damage.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Per your request, here's a link to a screenshot: http://ubuntuone.com/3cFoJyu7mt1oTMRJ5JtXJz

I also included the link in my original post.

Comment: Hrm, that's really wierd. I'll do my best to look into it. Have you tried other dock applications to see if it's specific to Docky? I would give Cairo a try and if there's no artifacts it might be a screen issue.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. Per your suggestion I tried Cairo and it didn't have this issue, so I think it's specific to Docky.

Comment: Man, that sucks. This could also be a screen + Docky specific, considering you have the other laptop working fine. I would file a bug report with the Docky guys.

Comment: Alright, will do. I appreciate your help.